# Java class with unicode code range specifications

Tags: java, unicode, localization, internationalization

Is there a class where the code ranges of unicode is defined as an enumeration or as constants? It's a very simple class where the code range specification (can be found anywhere like this for example: http://www.ssec.wisc.edu/~tomw/java/unicode.html) is put into a class, but this is a lot of boring work and I wish someone else has done it before!

Comment: You haven't accepted any answers for your questions (http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask )

Answer (score 5):

See [java.lang.Character.UnicodeBlock](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Character.UnicodeBlock.html).